# How a method can be called without object reference

Tags: java, android, object-reference, method-call

I am learning android and I am newbie. I encountered a code i.e.

```
FramgmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
```

I know that `getFragmentManager()` is a method defined in `Activity` class.

In java we access method through object reference that is `obj.method()` but here how can we call `getFragmentMananger` without any object refrence

Answer (score 3):

In your case there is an 'automatic' `this` reference meaning that your method is called on the enclosing object you're using right now (an Activity).

Comment: and what about method setContentView().Is this method same as this.setcContentView()

Comment: class student{
 String hello(){
  return "aaaaa";
 }
 
}


public class Dell extends student{

 public static void main(String[] args) {
   
   System.out.println("....");
   String a= hello();
   
 }

} bur here why it is error in line...String a=hello(); why it cant be this.hello();

Comment: In a static method, like main, there is no `this` to refer to.